# Incrementing the value of POSIX semaphores by more than 1

Tags: c, linux, posix, semaphore

I have this requirement wherein I have to increment the value of a POSIX semaphore by more than 1.

Apparently, there is no way in POSIX specification to do this. There is no sem_setvalue() similar to sem_getvalue(). I do not want to go back to System V semaphores just because of this constraint.

Is there any alternative way to accomplish this? Or will I have to go the System V way?

I am programming in C on GNU/Linux.

Great thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have this requirement wherein I have to increment the value of a POSIX semaphore by more than 1.
>   Is there any alternative way to accomplish this? Or will I have to go the System V way?

So what is your question really? How to implement something not supported by interface? Or how to create a structure behaving like [semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) using POSIX?

If this is later, before resorting to heavy guns like SysV, you can always use the `pthread_mutex_t`/`pthread_cond_t` pair to implement pretty much any multi-threading synchronization primitive, semaphore included.

E.g., untested:

```
typedef cool_sem {
    pthread_mutex_t guard;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
    int count;
} cool_sem_t;

void init( cool_sem_t *s )
{
    pthread_mutex_init( &s->guard, 0 );
    pthread_cond_init( &s->cond, 0 );
    s->S = 0;
}

void incr( cool_sem_t *s, unsigned delta )
{
    assert( s );
    pthread_mutex_lock( &s->guard );
    s->S += delta;
    pthread_cond_broadcast( &s->cond );
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &s->guard );
}

void decr( cool_sem_t *s, unsigned delta )
{
    assert( s );
    pthread_mutex_lock( &s->guard );
    do {
        if (s->S >= delta) {
            s->S -= delta;
            break;
        }
        pthread_cond_wait( &s->cond, &s->guard );
    } while (1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &s->guard );
}
```

Comment: There are several problems with this implementation. The variable `count` does not reflect the number of processes waiting on the semaphore. And the processes doing `decr()` with lower `delta` value will mostly take precedence over the processes with higher `delta` value, which might cause starvation.

Answer (score 1):

`semctl` and `semop` are what you need.Use GETVAL SETVAL in smectl for getter and setter.Set sem_op in **sembuf** struct to what you want to do with the semaphore when using semop. See man for more.

Comment: These work on System V semaphores, which the OP explicitly excluded.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such alternative when working with `sem_t`. If you have not yet done so, read the `sem_overview` man page on linux. The calls that are listed there are all you can get: initialization to a specific value, increment and decrement by one.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the complete specification, I think your teacher wants you to come up with a mechanism that will allow you to increment a semaphore by more than one atomically. So my guess is that one of your tasks is to synchronize the incrementation.

Comment: That is partly true. One of the options is to make the incrementation atomic. But I would like to know whether or not there is an "elegant" alternative to that in POSIX (the way there is in SysV)