# How can I Increment a POSIX sem_t semaphore by more than 1?

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore

Can I have a sem_t (semaphore) object take an a value of more than 1? Since sem_post only increments by 1. Is there a sem_set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a sem_t can take on a value of more than 1. You can use `sem_init` to initialise your semaphore to an abitrary value. Quoting from [this link](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/posixsem.html):

> To initialize a semaphore, use
>   sem_init():
>
> ```
>   int sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned int value);
> ```
>
> - sem points to a semaphore object to
>     initialize
> - pshared is a flag
>     indicating whether or not the
>     semaphore should be shared with
>     fork()ed processes. LinuxThreads does
>     not currently support shared
>     semaphores
> - value is an initial value
>     to set the semaphore to
>
> Example of
>   use:
>
> ```
>   sem_init(&sem_name, 0, 10);
> ```

I'm not aware of any function that can increment a sem_t by an arbitrary value.

Comment: See also this question, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491762/incrementing-the-value-of-posix-semaphores-by-more-than-1

Comment: pshared does not make the semaphore shared with forked children. It's only useful if the semaphore is created in memory that's already shared, and in this case, the pshared semaphore can be shared with any other processes that can map the shared memory, not just children.