# Recreate sem_wait() with mutex?

Tags: c, mutex

Is there **any way** so I can have up to 10 threads in the same `mutex`?

Something like `sem_wait()` with value `10`.

**Edit:**

Found this:

it is an implementation of semaphores, using mutexes and condition variables.

```
typedef struct {
  int value, wakeups;
  Mutex *mutex;
  Cond *cond;
} Semaphore;

// SEMAPHORE

Semaphore *make_semaphore (int value)
{
  Semaphore *semaphore = check_malloc (sizeof(Semaphore));
  semaphore->value = value;
  semaphore->wakeups = 0;
  semaphore->mutex = make_mutex ();
  semaphore->cond = make_cond ();
  return semaphore;
}

void sem_wait (Semaphore *semaphore)
{
  mutex_lock (semaphore->mutex);
  semaphore->value--;

  if (semaphore->value < 0) {
    do {
      cond_wait (semaphore->cond, semaphore->mutex);
    } while (semaphore->wakeups < 1);
    semaphore->wakeups--;
  }
  mutex_unlock (semaphore->mutex);
}

void sem_signal (Semaphore *semaphore)
{
  mutex_lock (semaphore->mutex);
  semaphore->value++;

  if (semaphore->value <= 0) {
    semaphore->wakeups++;
    cond_signal (semaphore->cond);
  }
  mutex_unlock (semaphore->mutex);
}
```

Comment: A mutex is designed to allow exactly one consumer (thread, process, whatever) to "have" it. As such, a mutex is a special case of a semaphore (a binary semaphore, to be exact). It's hard to implement a counting semaphore using only mutexes.

Comment: I think it can be done with mutexes and condition variables but i am kind of lost.. :S

Comment: See if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491762/incrementing-the-value-of-posix-semaphores-by-more-than-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, A mutex is a simple lock, having two states: locked and unlocked. When it is created, a mutex is unlocked. **A mutex is a mutual exclusion lock. Only one thread can hold the lock.**

Although you can implement to allow ten threads to enter in a section using `mutex` and `if` and a `global variable`. (the way count semaphores are implemented)

Read here: [**Implementing a Counting Semaphore**](http://www.csee.wvu.edu/~jdm/classes/cs550/notes/tech/mutex/semimp3.html)
One Available implementation: [**C code**](http://read.pudn.com/downloads180/sourcecode/unix_linux/837209/hw2.c__.htm) ,   [**Make your own semaphore**](http://content.yudu.com/Library/A1tr3x/TheLittleBookofSemap/resources/275.htm)

Comment: "A semaphore is like a combination of a mutex and a condition variable. ".

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/102796-pthread_cond_wait-vs-sem_wait.html

Comment: @BillSkiadas Yes I am not denying. But `mutex` doesn't allow [**multiple threads to lock.**](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.genprogc%2Fdoc%2Fgenprogc%2Fmutexes.htm)

Comment: @hGrijesh Chauhan All i am saying is that it can be implemented with Mutex and Condition variables..

Comment: @BillSkiadas  Yes good idea! you can use a `count variable` and increment and decrement variable atomically using mutex.

Comment: @BillSkiadas I updated & added a link in my answer hope you find helpful

Comment: @BillSkiadas Where/how did you find this? give a link!

Comment: Somewhere in stack overflow.. Sorry i closed the tab.. :)

Answer (score 2):

See If that Helps

> From Book **Begining Linux programming** a counting semaphore that
>   takes a wider range of values.  Normally,semaphores are used to
>   protect a piece of code so  that only one thread of execution can run
>   it at any one time. For this job a binary semaphore is needed.
>   Occasionally, you want to permit a limited number  of threads to
>   execute a given piece of code;  for this you would use a **counting
>   semaphore**

Comment: Is there any way to implement it with mutexes and condition Variables?