# How should I simulate sem_wait with a count?

Tags: c, posix, semaphore

I'm using `semaphore.h` and would like to acquire a semaphore if `n` instead of just one slot is available. Posix does not provide this natively. How can I work around that? I'm bound to using semaphores, no other means of synchronization are possible.

I'm pondering using a binary semaphore with a separate counter variable, but that would, in my opinion, kind of defeat its purpose.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491762 -- only states that this is not natively supported, but does not offer an alternative without SysV

Comment: The Answer at that link implements a semaphore using `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_cond_t`. Can't you use that?

Comment: You can do a `sem_trywait` with a count simply by trywaiting count times, and if any fails, `sem_post` as many times as it succeeded to reset the timer. (Similarly, `sem_post` with a count just calls `sem_post` count times.).   If you want a blocking wait, you need to have two semaphores in a struct, which means having to wrap all the standard `sem_xxx` functions. Is that acceptable to you?

Comment: Can you use system V semaphores instead of POSIX ones?  The SysV version is harder to use, but I think it does support the behavior you describe.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. @mtijanic, no, this is part of an assignment, and it appears they insist on semaphores (and posix).

Comment: @mtijanic Your idea is interesting. Do I understand correctly that it uses a binary "outside" semaphore while the inner semaphore does the `trywait`s? Seems close to a mutex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have multiple threads contending for slots of the semaphore (else you wouldn't need semaphores at all), you need to protect against deadlock.  For example, if your semaphore has four slots, and each of two threads is trying to acquire three, then they will deadlock if each manages to acquire two.  It follows that you must protect access to the process of acquiring semaphore slots.

A binary semaphore protecting a counter is not sufficient to prevent the deadlock scenario described above.  Moreover, if not enough slots are available at any given time then you must have some synchronous means to wait for more slots to become available.  You can do the job with two semaphores, though, one to protect access to the semaphore acquisition process, and another carrying the actual slots being acquired.  Something like this, for example:

```
#define DO_OR_RETURN(x) do { int _r; if ((_r = (x))) return _r; } while (0)

typedef struct multi_sem {
    sem_t sem_acquire_sem;
    sem_t multislot_sem;
} multisem;

int multisem_init(multisem *ms, unsigned int slots) {
    DO_OR_RETURN(sem_init(&ms->sem_acquire_sem, 0, 1));
    return sem_init(&ms->multislot_sem, 0, slots);
}

int multisem_wait(multisem *ms, unsigned int slots_to_acquire) {
    int result;
    DO_OR_RETURN(sem_wait(&ms->sem_acquire_sem));

    while (slots_to_acquire) {
        result = sem_wait(&ms->multislot_sem);
        switch (result) {
            case 0:
                slots_to_acquire -= 1;
                break;
            case EINTR:
                /* interrupted by a signal; try again */
                break;
            default:
                /* undocumented error - should never happen */
                /* insert appropriate apocalypse response here */
                slots_to_acquire = 0; /* bail out */
                break;
        }
    }

    if (sem_post(&ms->sem_acquire_sem)) {
        /* big oops - no recovery possible - should never happen */
        /* insert appropriate apocalypse response here */
    }

    return result;
}

int multisem_post(multisem *ms, unsigned int slots_to_post) {
    while (slots_to_post) {
        DO_OR_RETURN(sem_post(&ms->multislot_sem));
        slots_to_post -= 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Do note that that is still susceptible to deadlock in the event that a thread tries to acquire slots of the `multisem` when it already holds at least one (among other ways).  I think that risk is inherent in the problem.